# Error " 91" Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set the value of a cell with one of the function parameters. The code is giving an error 91. The 6th line in the code is raising the error:

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub report_file(a, r_row)
Dim wb_dst As Workbook
Dim ws_dst As Worksheet
Set wb_dst = Workbooks.Open("F:\Projects\vba_excel\report.xlsx")
ws_dst = wb_dst.Sheets(1)
ws_dst.Cells(r_row, 2).Value =a
End Sub
```

The error line is:

```
ws_dst.Cells(r_row, 2).Value =a
```

Comment: 6th line? remove Set in this line `Set wb_dst.cell(r_row, 2).Value = a` and give us a feedback what is going wrong now.

Comment: what's the value of 'a' and what's the value of 'r_row'?  Also you have a typo in your if statement.  It should be wb_dst.Cells and not wb_dst.cell.  Actually I'm pretty sure you don't need that if statement at all..unless you're just doing it as a test.

Comment: @KazJaw : it shows the same error "91"

Comment: cite error line here... and what are values of `r_row` and `a` variables when error raise?

Comment: the error line is " ws_dst.Cells(r_row, 2).Value =a " , the value of a is a string , and the value of r_row=2.

Comment: add `Set` instruction to this line `ws_dst = wb_dst.Sheets(1)` to create `Set ws_dst = wb_dst.Sheets(1)`

Comment: Your 5th line needs a `Set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub report_file(a, r_row)
    Dim wb_dst As Workbook
    Dim ws_dst As Worksheet
    Set wb_dst = Workbooks.Open("F:\Projects\vba_excel\report.xlsx")
    Set ws_dst = wb_dst.Sheets(1)
    ws_dst.Cells(r_row, 2).Value = a
    If a = "savior" Then
        wb_dst.Cells(r_row, 2).Value = a
    End If
End Sub
```